# Firebase: Database reference 'on' method not running callback (javascript)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm tunning a query for data that may not exist . When this is the case, the callback is not run. As I understand from the docs, it should run and the snapshot.val() should be null, isn't it?

There's a stripped down example here: http://surfmaps.eu/trombone/case.html

There's a console.log inside the callback that is not executed.

Am I missing something here?

Bye and thanks, Luís

Code:

```
function getData(id) {
    var ref=firebase.database().ref("support/"+id); 
    console.log("In getData, looking for ",ref);

    // get support data from firebase
    ref.on('value',function (snapshot) {
        console.log("In Value");
        console.log(snapshot);
    });

    console.log("end getData, looking for ",ref);

}

// on startup
getData("abc");
```

Comment: The code seems to be working for me.  Which `console.log` isn't being fired?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You don't have permission to read the data. To see this, you can attach a completion listener and log the error it gives you:

```
var ref=firebase.database().ref("support/"+id); 
console.log("In getData, looking for ",ref);

// get support data from firebase
ref.on('value',function (snapshot) {
    console.log("In Value");
    console.log(snapshot);
}, function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});

console.log("end getData, looking for ",ref);
```

Doing so shows:

> Error: permission_denied at /support/abc: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

Comment: I had been looking for some error callback, but hadn't realized there was one, even after reading the docs. In fact, this callback appears labeled as 'cancelCallbackOrContext', which seems a bit misleading.

Thanks!

Comment: When you don't have permission to read, the listener is canceled - hence its name. But indeed there should be some documentation on it. Not sure where that went.

Answer (score 1):

See [Firebase Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart), You dont have permission to Access Firebase Database Collection.

Go to Firebase Console, Database, Rules to update:

```
{
  "support{
    ".read": true, // allow read
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

Comment: I stuck with this almost the whole day and you saved my life.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
function(error) {
console.error(error);
```

to find the error. It should be because of

> Error: permission_denied at /react: Client doesn't have permission to
>   access the desired data.

change that by going to realtime Database -> rules -> change the read and write to true from false.