# How to get Data from Firebase-Database in Real-Time with Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I would like to automatically generate an alert in realtime as soon as a value in my Firebase database has changed. My code looks like this:

```
try {
        var ref = firebase.database().ref("URL").child("1");
        ref.on("child_changed", function(snapshot) {
          var changedPost = snapshot.val();
          alert(changedPost);
        });
        }
        catch(err) {
          alert("Error");
        }
```

As you can see the structure of my database is:

[image: Here is a link to a picture of my firebase-database structure.]

Could someone tell me what is wrong with this code and why I don't get an alert when something changes in my database?

I would appreciate an answer.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the actual data in the database.  Without seeing that, and matching it to your code, we can't see what might actually be going wrong.  Also, your code isn't checking for errors anywhere.  Be sure to update your code to show that you're doing that as well.

Comment: @DougStevenson What do you mean? I have already written my database structure in the question...

Comment: A screenshot or JSON dump would be more precise and descriptive.  And please do check for errors.

Comment: @DougStevenson ok i added a picture of my Firebase-Database and a Error. But after I executed my Code nothing happend.

Comment: What you're doing for error  handling isn't going to work.  That catch isn't going to find any errors.  Consult the documentation for the correct method.  You will pass a another callback to handle errors.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41625639/firebase-database-reference-on-method-not-running-callback-javascript

Comment: Yes Thanks a Lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're listening for `child_changed` events, which fires when a property **under** `/URL/1` changes. To instead get called when the value **in** `/URL/1` changes, listen for a `value` event:

```
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  var changedPost = snapshot.val();
  alert(changedPost);
});
```